# TwitterKit Composer Logged in after being logged out.

Tags: android, twitter-fabric

So I have a SettingsActivity that allows you to Login using the Twitter Fabric sdk, and then in my MainActivity I am using the TwitterKit Tweet composer. When I log out of Twitter in the SettingsActivity, in my MainActivity I am still logged in and able to Tweet.